# Couldn't install justintime debugger.msi file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Once I update visual studio 2022, then set up warning showed justintime debugger.msi file could not be installed. after then again visual studio 2022 download  and visual studio installer with administrator mode  package installed and  again this type of set up warning show could not installed justintime.debugger. msi file. how to fix this warning message?

Comment: Merely a simple description is not enough. You need something like this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12493 to collect the related log. 

You need follow the below steps:

1 download Microsoft Visual Studio and .NET Framework log collection tool

https://aka.ms/vscollect

2 run Collect.exe in  an administrative command prompt

The tool generates a vslogs.zip file in your %TEMP% folder, typically at C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Temp\vslogs.zip.

Comment: For your situation, SO is not the suitable way to ask such question that will contains numerous related logs(Which may contains in-private info), For securty reason, this is a better place to report: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report